# Forward claims from external provider to Cognito Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have an app and openid identity server. My app retrieves tokens from the Identity server.

I have also configured the identity server as an external provider for an AWS Cognito Identity Pool.

I can successfully retrieve AWS credentials for the User logged into my app.

However, I find the AWS credentials limited as the token does not contain any of the claims from the original login token. Is there any way to get them in there?

One the claims I use is clientID and I was hoping to be able to use that in a an IAM Policy to restrict S3 access by client.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found direct solution for that, and it seems like missing feature.

The workaround I did was:

1. Mapping id_token/access_token/refresh_token to custom cognito attributes. As all mapped attributes are later available in your frontend, you need to restrict read permissions for sensitive attributes.
2. Use `TokenGeneration_HostedAuth` lambda trigger to work on this data.